# Elegant way to chain data transformations in Scala?

Tags: scala, design-patterns, coding-style

Suppose I have a list of functions, each expecting a certain type as input, and returning a value of the same type. For example a `String`.

The way these functions are used is in a chained fashion: the output of one is the input of the next one.

```scala
def oneTransform(input: String): String = { ... }
def anotherTransform(input: String): String = { ... } 
def yetAnotherTransform(input: String): String = { ... }
```

It could be used in a code like this:

```scala
val input = "my-initial-input"
val input2 = oneTransform(input)
val input3 = anotherTransform(input2)
val output = yetAnotherTransform(input3)
```

Is there a more elegant way to express this is Scala?

This is very un-elegant and error-prone, and I thought maybe Scala (or a Scala library) offers a nicer way to write this.

Monads? foldLeft?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Looking at `compose` and `andThen` now. Might do what I need.