# Scala apply list of functions to a object

Tags: scala

I have a lit of functions

```
val f1 = (x: Int) => x + 1
val f2 = (x: Int) => x + 2
val f3 = (x: Int) => x + 3
```

I have a single value:

```
val data = 5
```

I want to apply all the functions to the value and return single value. So

```
f3(f2(f1(data)))
```

And must return 11.

Now, if I have a seq of functions:

```
val funcs = Seq(f1, f2, f3)
```

How can I get `11` from applying all the functions to the `data` variable ? What is the scala-way to do that ?

Comment: Basically a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338029/elegant-way-to-chain-data-transformations-in-scala which itself was closed as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349480/apply-several-string-transformations-in-scala that is indeed equivalent if not as close in wording

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply several string transformations in scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349480/apply-several-string-transformations-in-scala)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are looking for is `foldLeft`. Indeed, for each function, you apply it to the previous result:

```
funcs.foldLeft(data){ (previousres, f) => f(previousres) }
```

Answer (score 12):

yet another way to doing it using `chain` method in the `Function` helper object

```
Function.chain(funcs)(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `foldLeft`:

```
val result = funcs.foldLeft(5)((acc,curr) => curr(acc) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you are trying to achieve `Function Composition` here. So, you could use `compose` and `andThen` methods here as:

```
    val data = 5

    val funcs = Seq(f1, f2, f3)

    //using compose
    val result1 = funcs.reduce((a,b) => a.compose(b))(data)

    //using andThen
    val result2 = funcs.reduce((a,b) => a.andThen(b))(data)
```

Both `result1` and `result2` will be **11** in your example.

Please note that the way `andThen` and `compose` operate are different. You could see [Functional Composition](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/pattern-matching-and-functional-composition.html) for more information.